# apt-maven-plugin not generating QClass for entities with @Entity notation

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, querydsl

hope u're well.

Here's the thing, I'm trying to use dslQuery with spring-boot in order to get an advanced search out of the box, but the maven plugin won't generate the TClass for the entities.

pom.xml

```
<project ...>
    ...

    <properties>
        <!-- General -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>

        <!-- Plugins -->
        <com.mysema.maven.apt-maven-plugin.version>1.1.3</com.mysema.maven.apt-maven-plugin.version>

        <!-- Dependencies -->
        <com.querydsl.version>4.2.1</com.querydsl.version>

        <org.springframework.boot.version>2.1.4.RELEASE</org.springframework.boot.version>

        <org.hibernate.javax.persistence.version>1.0.1.Final</org.hibernate.javax.persistence.version>
        <org.hibernate.hibernate-core.version>5.4.1.Final</org.hibernate.hibernate-core.version>

        <org.junit.platform.junit-platform-surefire-provider.version>1.0.1
        </org.junit.platform.junit-platform-surefire-provider.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        ...

        <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${org.apache.maven.plugins.maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                        <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${com.mysema.maven.apt-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>process</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
                                <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${org.springframework.boot.version}</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        ...

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <version>${com.querydsl.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.boot.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Persistence -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.hibernate.javax.persistence.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.hibernate.hibernate-core.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

example entity:

```
package com.expenses.core.expense.entities;

import com.expenses.core.common.entities.AbstractEntity;
import com.expenses.core.utils.Copyable;

import javax.annotation.Nonnull;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity(name = "Account")
@Table(name = "account")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "account_generator", sequenceName = "account_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
public class Account extends AbstractEntity<Account> implements Copyable<Account> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "account_generator")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    private final String cbu;

    private final String alias;

    private final String bank;

    private final String description;

}
```

I know there are some post like this on the forums, and in google, but after trying what was in those posts, the problem persists.

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

PS: The AccountRepository does extend from `JpaRepository<Account, Long>` and `QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Account>`.

Comment: Please post only the relevant sections of the code.

Comment: Sry about that, it's been removed.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know what was wrong with the plugin configuration, but I came across with this, and it did the trick (after removing the plugin from the pom).
Hope it helps someone

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
    <version>${com.querydsl.version}</version>
    <classifier>jpa</classifier>
</dependency>
```

PS: I'd love to know why my old configuration wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me without the outputDirectory.

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${com.mysema.maven.apt-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Maybe the classes generated on the target folder were out of reach?